# iFrame not loading URL

Tags: html, iframe

I am using the following simple iFrame code to load Yahoo but it's not loading anyway. in Chrome Inspector I see the URL status as 301 first and then cancel. Any idea why is it happening?

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: You might want to consider marking an answer as correct.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You probably get an error message in the log that reads something like this:

`"Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."`

To answer your question:

Yahoo is doing this to `avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.`

For more info read this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: +1, this has come up a number of times and has always been the case.

Answer (score 11):

Its also very easy to ask site not to load if you are in an iframe with simple javascript. For example, twitter does this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    if (window.top !== window.self) {
        document.write = "";
        window.top.location = window.self.location;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
        }, 1);
        window.self.onload = function (evt) {
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
        }; 
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

I did not see a console error here and so I guess this is the case here.

The Yahoo! JavaScript is obfuscated but you can see they are definitely removing something at this snippet. (Code taken from yahoo website)

```
if(self!==self.top){b=function(){if(g.readyState=="complete"){f.remove(g,e,b);
```

Comment: I think your reply is not really answer the asked question.

Comment: Indirectly he did answer, provided the reason of it. Before his answer I was thinking that there is some issue at my end. I also learnt how to save my side for any embedding.Thanks @naveen

Comment: It means one cant use Yahoo or amazon with StumbleUpon?

Comment: @Volatil3: I guess so. I am not used to StumbleUpon. Yahoo.com doesn't have any stumbles anyway.

Answer (score 8):

If the site hosting the webpage forces the use of a secure `HTTPS` connection, some browsers (chrome for sure) will require that all network resources use `HTTPS` as well.

The URL in your current iframe is using HTTP `src="http://yahoo.com"`

**Try using HTTPS: `src="https://yahoo.com"`**

Comment: This is the only correct answer! In my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

actually yahoo , google and such website doesn't allow iframes to their site. They blocks iframes to show their website

Answer (score 0):

My latest Firefox silently refused to load an unencrypted iframe when the parent was unencrypted.  It showed no console messages about an attempt to load the child or any reason to not try doing so.