# Toggle iFrame with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Thanks in advance for your help!
My JavaScript skills are pretty limited.

I'm working with a wordpress site, trying to toggle between two iFrames.

I have a code which works but I would like to make the button as one button instead of two, as it currently stands. I've searched for hours and can't seems to find a solution.

Also, I can't use jquery.

Here is what I have, thank you!

```js
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("two");
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);
buttonTwo.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

function buttonClick(e){
    if(e.target.id === "one"){
        iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/";
    }else{
        iframe.src = "https://www.ask.com/";
    } 
};
```

```html
<button id="one">List View</button>
<button id="two">Calendar View</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1115px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why you tagged java too in the question?

Comment: What do you mean by `one button`? What should happen when you press it? Redirect you to the first website or to the second one?

Comment: Refer The link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268226/iframe-not-loading-url

Comment: Create a variable (ex:var frame='google'). Keep one event listener. In the callback of your event listener, check the value of the variable frame. If the value is 'google', set the src (as you do actually) and change the value of frame to 'ask'. Vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Try using array of `src`

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var srcs = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.ask.com/"];
var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

function buttonClick(e) {
  iframe.src = srcs[i];
  console.log('loading src', srcs[i]);
  i = ((1 + i) % srcs.length);
};

btn.click(); /* load first on page load */
```

```html
<button id="btn">Toggle View</button>
<iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1115px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code:
Creating HTML:

```
<button id="one" data-view_type="calendar">Toggle View</button>
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1115px"></iframe>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var buttonOne = document.getElementById("one");
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");

buttonOne.addEventListener("click", buttonClick, false);

function buttonClick(e){
    var btnObj = e.target;
    var view_type = btnObj.getAttribute("data-view_type");
    if(view_type === "list"){
        iframe.src = "https://www.google.com/";
        btnObj.setAttribute("data-view_type", "calendar");
    }else{
        iframe.src = "https://www.ask.com/";
        btnObj.setAttribute("data-view_type", "list");
    } 
};
```